# Connecting to SQL Server from PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I currently have a SQL Server working and running properly, except for the fact that I cannot connect from my web application built in PHP.

Whenever I try to connect to the server I get the following error:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 258
> [code] => 258 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]TCP
> Provider: Tiempo de espera de la operación de espera agotado.
> [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]TCP Provider:
> Tiempo de espera de la operación de espera agotado. ) [1] => Array (
> [0] => HYT00 [SQLSTATE] => HYT00 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] =>
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired
> [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Login timeout
> expired ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 258
> [code] => 258 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]A
> network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while
> establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not
> accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is
> configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL
> Server Books Online. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL
> Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while
> establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not
> accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is
> configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL
> Server Books Online. ) )

I tried out pretty much every single fix I found on StackOverflow and other websites, but none of them has worked.

Things I did confirm:

- Port 1433 is correctly open.
- The server is working properly, since I can open SQL Server Manager from a different computer that is outside the network, and I can log in to the server SQL by using public IP and password.
- There is no firewall issues. Every exception is added and also firewalls have been temporarily disabled to confirm.
- Remote connections are allowed and SQL Server configuration seems ok.

The PHP code that I use is not very complex:

```
$serverName = "111.111.111.111"; 
$connectionInfo = array( 
    "Database"=>"DBName", 
    "UID"=>"sa", 
    "PWD"=>"DBPWD", 
    "CharacterSet"=>"utf-8"
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if ( $conn ) {
     echo "Good";
} else {
     echo "Bad.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

I tried many different things like:

```
$serverName = "111.111.111.111\INSTANCE";
$serverName = "111.111.111.111/INSTANCE";
$serverName = "111.111.111.111, 1433";
```

But none of them has worked.

Again, I do not think it is a network problem since I can connect to the database from the outside with SQL Management Studio, but I just can't do it from the PHP application.

The code works when the script is run inside the network and the public IP is replaced by the hostname, which should tell that the code is ok too.

What could I be missing?

Comment: Thanks @user3647971 , if I use the local ip it works if the PHP script is running from the local network, but since the PHP script is being hosted on a different server than the SQL Server database, it wont work, that is why i'm trying to connect with the public IP.

Comment: Probably TCP/IP protocol is not enabled. A possible solution is this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49533539/php-sqlsrv-connect-to-sql-server-a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-h/49609670#49609670).