# Unable to connect MSSQL Server database using sqlsrv_connect

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, sqlsrv

This is a common topic and had been asked quite a few times before this. I already had gone through some of those but unable to make it to work.

I am trying to connect a `MSSQL Server` database from `PHP` using the following code.

```
$serverName = "cl-t139-086cn\\MSSQLSERVER"; //serverName\instanceName

$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"AutoTrader", "UID"=>"user_id", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

I tried the following two variations but none is working

`$serverName = (local)\MSSQLSERVER`
`$serverName = localhost\MSSQLSERVER`

The instance name is MSSQLSERVER, I checked in Windows services by running `services.mfc`.

Database username and password are also correct because the same credential is being used inside Web.config file of another running which is running from the same server but built with .NET.

The extension `sqlsrv` is installed and enabled OK which I already checked by running a `phoinfo()`.

This is the complete error displayed on page:

```
Connection could not be established. Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 87 [code] => 87 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SQL Server Network Interfaces: Connection string is not valid [87]. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SQL Server Network Interfaces: Connection string is not valid [87]. ) [1] => Array ( [0]
=> HYT00 [SQLSTATE] => HYT00 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 87 [code] => 87 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. ) )
```

*Environment:*

- OS: Windows Server 2016 (Windows 10)
- PHP: XAMPP
- PHP Version: 7.4.x
- Database: MSSQL Server
- Instance Name: MSSQLSERVER

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Probably a network configuration [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49533539/php-sqlsrv-connect-to-sql-server-a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-h/49609670#49609670).

Comment: You mean port is blocked? Everything is running from the same server.

Comment: Yes, you  may try to make a test and configure SQL Server not to use dynamic ports and choose a specific port with a firewall rule.

Comment: Can you please give me some detail about this?

Comment: 1). Simply follow the steps from the suggested answer. 2) Add the appropriate inbound rule in the Windows Firewall (if enabled). Thanks.

Comment: Try to use server IP to connect. Port blocked? Or firewall? Check this url: https://knowledgebase.apexsql.com/configure-remote-access-connect-remote-sql-server-instance-apexsql-tools/

Comment: When you use instance names in connection strings, even the default MSSQLSERVER instance name, you need to have at least two ports open for firewall access: udp/1434 for the SQL Browser service (which is an instance name lookup service that returns the actual port a named instance is listening on); and tcp/1433 for the default named instance, MSSQLSERVER - unless you happen to have reconfigured that to a different port in SQL Server (version) Configuration Manager > SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols for MSSQLSERVER > TCP/IP.